# What does it mean that an instance of StreamHandler uses sys.stderr by default?

Tags: python, logging

Python 3 [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler) state the following about `StreamHandler`:

> Returns a new instance of the `StreamHandler` class. If stream is specified, the instance will use it for logging output; otherwise, `sys.stderr` will be used.

What does this mean?

I use a `StreamHandler` instance, which I initialize without specifying a stream:

```
class MyLogger():
    def __init__(self, level):
        self.logger   = getLogger('MyLogger')
        self.debug    = self.logger.debug
        self.info     = self.logger.info
        self.warning  = self.logger.warning
        self.error    = self.logger.error
        self.critical = self.logger.critical
        streamHandler = StreamHandler()
        streamHandler.setLevel(level)
        self.logger.addHandler(streamHandler)
        self.logger.setLevel(level)

myLogger = MyLogger(DEBUG)
...
myLogger.debug('message')
```

But everything is printed to the console (i.e., `sys.stdout`).

So how exactly is `sys.stderr` involved here?

Comment: `stdout` and `stderr` both print to your console.  That is expected behavior.

Comment: `stdout` and `stderr` can be individually redirected within the shell but will both display on the console by default.

Comment: @larsks: Thank you!

Comment: @Feneric: Thank you!